# Copy the Data in All Files which in the Folder and Paste to the Master Data

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried something like similar question that someone asked before.
And now I am stuck at script.
I need to do all these steps :

1. I want to loop over all the files in a folder
2. Open the file
3. Copy the range. Notes:  The range is vary. But something like from A10:N(lastrow-2). Minus two is last two rows got additional information that we no need to consolidate.
4. Paste it into the other Master Workbook
5. Repeat but paste new data underneath

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFolder As Object
    Dim oFile As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim LR As Integer
    'For understanding LR = Last Row
 
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\user name\Downloads\Test Consolidate Folder")
 
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        Worksheets("FileName").Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next oFile

    LR = Workbooks("Consolidate").Worksheets("FileName").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set ListFileName = Workbooks("Consolidate").Worksheets("FileName").Cells(j + 1, 1)
    j = j + 1
    
    Workbooks(ListFileName).Worksheets("Parts").Range("A10:N" & (LR - 2)).Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: The Script error

Comment: You cannot copy anything without opening the workbooks in discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub CopyFilesContent()
    Dim oFSO As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR As Long, lastR As Long, wsFN As Worksheet
 
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\user name\Downloads\Test Consolidate Folder")
    Set wsFN = Workbooks("Consolidate").workshets("FileName")
    
    For Each oFile In oFolder.files
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile)    'open the workbook to copy from
          Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Parts") 'Parts sheet, to copy from. Use here the necessary one if not this
        LR = wsFN.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1       'last empty row in the master FileName sheet
        wsFN.cells(LR) = oFile.Name                            'write the wb to copy from name
        lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row - 2'last row in the sheet where to copy from
        ws.Range("A10:N" & lastR).Copy wsFN.Range("A" & LR + 1)'copy the necessary range
        wb.Close False  'close the workbook, without saving it
    Next oFile
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply . I've copy and try your code and change which necessary. It turn up the error code '9'. Subscript out of range .